# Map dataFrame values to another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have these two dataFrames

```
data1 = [[1,'A'],[2,'B'],[3,'C'],[4,'D'],[5,'E']]
data2 = [1,1,1,1,2,5,4,3]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns = ['one','two'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns = ['one'])
```

I want to map all values of df2 of column `one` with df1 of column `two`. In simple terms i want to use df1 as a dictionary. I want output like this for df2

```
   one
0    A
1    A
2    A
3    A
4    B
5    E
6    D
7    C
```

I am doing this

```
df2['one']= df2['one'].apply(lambda x: df1.two[df1.one == x])
```

Which gives me output

```
   one
0    A
1    A
2    A
3    A
4  NaN
5  NaN
6  NaN
7  NaN
```

All A is correct but why latter all are NaN?

Comment: Basically, you are facing some index alignment issues generated by usign pd.Series.apply... my solution below for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, much better syntax and functionality over using `apply` with a lambda function:

```
df2['one'].map(df1.set_index('one')['two'])
```

Output:

```
0    A
1    A
2    A
3    A
4    B
5    E
6    D
7    C
Name: one, dtype: object
```

---

Why your method doesn't work.... Look at the output of :

```
df2['one'].apply(lambda x: df1.two[df1.one == x])
```

Output:

```
     0    1    2    3    4
0    A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1    A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2    A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3    A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN    B  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    E
6  NaN  NaN  NaN    D  NaN
7  NaN  NaN    C  NaN  NaN
```

Because of index alignment in pandas only the first column, 0. get assigned. Here, you are using `pd.Series.apply` where you are applying the lambda function over the elements of a series and assigning it back to a dataFrame causing your mal-alignment issues.

Comment: This is exactly what i want but why didn't apply work in my case

Answer (score 2):

dict df1 columns and map to df2.

```
df2.one=df2.one.map(dict(zip(df1.one,df1.two)))

  one
0   A
1   A
2   A
3   A
4   B
5   E
6   D
7   C
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve that by performing a join.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [[1,'A'],[2,'B'],[3,'C'],[4,'D'],[5,'E']]
data2 = [1,1,1,1,2,5,4,3]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns = ['one','two'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns = ['one'])

print(df1)

print(df2)

merge_df = pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['one'])[['two']]
print(merge_df)
```

output

two
0   A
1   A
2   A
3   A
4   B
5   C
6   D
7   E

Answer (score 0):

```
df2.one = df2.one.map(dict(zip(df1.one,df1.two)))
```

I have tried this solution and it works for me:

[image]